Both access point and wifi connection on the same device (Network Manager solution)
I am running a brand new Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W on latest (stable) Raspberry Pi OS Lite (64-bit).
I am trying to set it up using Network Manager (nmcli) to be connected to my home Wi-Fi router AND have an access point at the same time.
I should eventually be able to connect to the access point using my phone and still browse the internet, the traffic should be going through the Raspberry Pi and go to my home router.
Phone -> Raspberry Pi Access Point -> Home Router
I have been able to set up the Wi-Fi connection between RPI and home router, and the RPI access point; but only in a mutually exclusive way, meaning when I enter sudo nmcli con up accesspoint, the RPI disconnects from my home router and now only works in Access Point mode.
I know that the RPI Zero only has one network device wlan0, does this mean what I am trying to achieve is not possible ?
How to set up both a Wi-Fi connection and Access Point (and share internet connection) on the RPI Zero ?
Do I need to create some kind of "virtual" device or interface to have both running at the same time ?
Note: I have already read through the two most popular articles that I was able to find online on the topic (https://blog.thewalr.us/2017/09/26/raspberry-pi-zero-w-simultaneous-ap-and-managed-mode-wifi/ and https://imti.co/iot-wifi/) but those are not using nmcli. I am looking for a Network Manager "modern" way of achieving this.
Sorry if I am not using the exact technical networking terminology, I am fairly new to this kind of "intermediate" network configurations, though I have been using RPI for years now.
Thank you so much for your help, I already spent hours trying things that I found online but still didn't manage to achieve my goal :(
EDIT:
What I have done:

Configure Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W on latest (stable) Raspberry Pi OS Lite (64-bit) using 64 GB SD card and RPI imager with preconfigured network Wi-Fi connection (on home router) and SSH enabled
I then SSH into RPI and set up a new Wi-Fi hotspot using the following commands:

sudo nmcli con add type wifi ifname wlan0 mode ap con-name accesspoint ssid "hotspot" autoconnect true
sudo nmcli con modify accesspoint 802-11-wireless.band bg ipv4.method shared ipv4.address 192.168.6.1/24
sudo nmcli con modify accesspoint ipv6.method disabled
sudo nmcli con modify accesspoint wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
sudo nmcli con modify accesspoint wifi-sec.psk "hotspot1234"
sudo nmcli con up accesspoint


My SSH connection was terminated, I connected through the new access point (instead of home router) and SSH back into the RPI.
When I run nmcli con show I now have my access point on wlan0 but the preconfigured connection is not assigned to any device.
I think that I need additional configuration to have both the preconfigured connection and the access point connection running on wlan0 (or some kind virtual interface/bridge), but I don't know how.


It is possible (easier with dhcpcd) but I have done so by following documentation.  You have failed to document WHAT YOU HAVE DONE. Note reading ancient posts is unlikely to be helpful. Using a basic Pi with only one network interface is probably next to impossible unless you use Ethernet over USB .

@Milliways I added a section with what I have done. I read many posts online where people managed to have both AP and wifi connection on single interface but not using nmcli. Why it would be possible using dhcpcd but not nmcli ? Is it not supported by nmcli (or is this tool too basic for more advanced network configurations ?)

AFAIK no one has done with dhcpcd. Debian networking did permit virtual interfaces but not dhcpcd. Of cause this comes with all the limitations of Debian networking. I haven't used this for 8-9 years. If you want to make an AP with network access you should chose a platform with multiple interfaces. If you are happy to do this you can still use Debian networking because it does work. I have heard that systemd networkd can do this but configuration is difficult.

You could try with wlan0:1
